# pip vs conda in anaconda enviroment

Tags: python

I am using anaconda and I created a environment. when I run the model in spyder, it says no module named pandas. So I went back to the environment and tried to install pandas using pip install pandas. It says, requirement already satisfied, then I did: conda install pandas, then it has below information to install pandas. so now my question is, which one should I use,  pip or conda when installing a package? I remembered installing tensorflow, I have to use pip instead of conda. then I opened spyder again and ran the code, there was still an error of no module named 'pandas' . Then I went back to environment cmd again, from ipython, I can find the version of pandas. I am confused, why spyder doesn't recognize pandas? anyone here help me clarify it? Thanks

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates                      2020.12.8-haa95532_0 --> 2021.1.19-haa95532_0
  pandas                               1.2.0-py38hf11a4ad_0 --> 1.2.1-py38hf11a4ad_0


Proceed ([y]/n)?


In [1]: import sys

In [2]: print(sys.version_info)
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

In [3]: import pandas

In [4]: print(pandas.__version__)
1.2.1

In [5]:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have two different python interpreters on your system. Seems that your IDE/project is set up to use anaconda and your system terminal is defaulting to the one that came with your system.

You can use `which python` command on system terminal and also in IDE terminal to verify this.

Comment: Thank yes, I am using where.exe python, and it shows 3 python like below. do I need to uninstall python.exe under windowsApps? Thanks   (tf_cpu) C:\Users\yongn>where.exe python
C:\Users\yongn\miniconda3\envs\tf_cpu\python.exe
C:\Users\yongn\miniconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\yongn\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

Comment: You can edit your path to refer to the miniconda executable if you want to sync your system terminal with your IDE. However I would suggest you take some time to understand virtual environments (looks like you already made one called tf_cpu). This would allow you to maintain clean envs for different projects going forward.

Comment: Thanks Ash, I think this python was installed when I installed microsoft visual studio this afternoon. How could I uninstall this python under C:\Users\yongn\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ ? Thanks

Comment: I have not used Windows for awhile but I believe you should be able to do it from Control Panel. However I suggest simply editing your account's system variables instead. Even if you uninstall this python, you will probably still have to add the miniconda one to path.

Comment: Thanks Ash, yes I removed the path variable directing to windowsApp python. Now it shows I am using python from anaconda. so I re-installed pandas using conda install pandas. However there is still an error of no modules named pandas when running in spyder. any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Ok 1. What are you using to run conda install? 2. What does it show when you run which python where you are running conda install? 3. Is there a terminal inside Spyder? What does it show when you run which python there?

Comment: Thanks Ash, I am using anaconda prompt and switch to enviroment using conda activate tf, from there I installed conda install pandas, after that, I launch syper by typing spyder

Comment: Ok if you were using anaconda prompt then the windows python probably did not matter to begin with. So you are installing pandas in the tf conda env. Is Spyder also using this conda env or not?

Comment: yes Ash, i installed spyder using conda install spyder before

Comment: Hi Ash, I think I was using pip install spyder before. Now I redo it using conda install spyder and I think i solved the problem. Now my question is when do I use pip or conda? Can you give me a suggestion? I am confused. Do I just use conda install all the time under anaconda prompt?

Comment: You should be able to open a terminal in Spyder. Please type which python there. See if it is using the one fron tf or not. Probably not. You will have to configure the project to use the conda env. Pls google how to do that.

Comment: Even if using a conda env, pip would work. pip and conda simply pull from different repositories. You can use either, just be consistent else there might be issues when generating your requirements.txt file.

Comment: Thank you so much Ash, I really appreciate your helping me. Problem is solved. Have a good night!

Comment: Great to hear that. Please help accept the answer.